# Save music file to internal storage from sdacard

Tags: android, file, file-io, bitmap

I have been trying to save the file ( soundtrack ) from sdcard to the internal storage.
I have already done so with the image with this code

```
ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
     // path to /data/data/fairyTale/app_data/ImgMsc
    File directory = cw.getDir("ImgMsc", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    // Create imageDir
    File mypath=new File(directory,Name+".png");

    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {           

        fos = new FileOutputStream(mypath);

   // Use the compress method on the BitMap object to write image to the OutputStream
        bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        fos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Now this works well, creates a directory and saves my bitmap, but i want to do the same thing for the music file.
Also i want to know how to read that file ( use it in the app ).
I have used this code to read the bitmap

```
File f=new File(path,name+".png");
        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f));
        return b;
```

---

P.S. the code i have tried, but doesn't seem to be producing the right copy:

```
String filePath=Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)+"/"+name;
    File music = new File(filePath);
    ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
    // path to /data/data/fairyTale/app_data/ImgMsc
    File directory = cw.getDir("ImgMsc", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    File mypath=new File(directory,name+".mp3");
    try {
    InputStream is=new FileInputStream(music);
    OutputStream os;
    os = new FileOutputStream(mypath);
    byte[] buff=new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while((len=is.read(buff))>0){
            os.write(buff,0,len);
        }
        is.close();
        os.close();
    }
```

Comment: Sounds like you simply need to find any of the countless examples of doing a file copy operation (read a buffer, write a buffer, repeat until done) in Java.

Comment: Well i kinda went through a lot, and i keep getting file not found exception in the input stream, i just taught that there is a special way to it, as it is for the image.

Comment: That would imply you had the wrong path for the source.  Be aware that on recent Android versions, apps may see the External Storage at a different path than tools like ADB/DDMS do.

Comment: Well, i don't think that it's because i have the wrong path, because then image path ( which is the same thing ) would not work, i think the file for the input stream is created differently then the normal File f = new File(myPath);

Comment: As a test, you could see if you can copy your image (which you already know you can open) as arbitrary data rather than as a bitmap.  That might clarify if the problem is with your method, or with that particular source file.

Comment: I have used the normal method with input/output stream to transfer the file, but i cannot read it, my mediaplayer crashes, and i think it's because the file wasn't transferred correctly. That's why i want to find a method for transferring mp3 files.

Comment: Post the code which makes the possibly flawed copy.

Comment: Posted, check it out...

Comment: Actually, the code works.... I was having problems with the mediaplayer when it loaded the track, it wasn't crashing my app, but it was just black screen and i needed to shut down my device, i taught that's because the file was copied wrong, but the fault was in the mediaplayer, later i figured out that there was some problem with the .prepare() statement and finally it works. Thanks for trying to help mate, you are boss!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code that worked for me:

```
private void saveToInternalStorage(String name){
    String filePath=Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)+"/"+name;
    File music = new File(filePath);
    ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
    // path to your data
    File directory = cw.getDir("ImgMsc", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    File mypath=new File(directory,name+".mp3");
    // Create imageDir
    try {
    InputStream is=new FileInputStream(music);
    OutputStream os;
    os = new FileOutputStream(mypath);
    byte[] buff=new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while((len=is.read(buff))>0){
            os.write(buff,0,len);
        }
        is.close();
        os.close();
    DeleteFile(filePath);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Hope it helps!